# Material persists even after being deleted

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I created a Blender Render material and added color, after that i changed to cycles render and selected use nodes, now material color persists even after deleting the original material so any material i apply result in a darker color than when i apply it to new objects.

It is as if the original color had been baked to the mesh so now it´s darker than normal even if i remove all materials from it.

I may have done something else but i can`t recall, i deleted the automatically generated data in node editor (Material and Out, still in blender render)

Im joining now the original mesh with a new one and it is always bicolor, i can change color by applying a single new material and works for both pieces but the new mesh is always lighter than the original one.

Comment: I'm rather confused. What render engine are you using now? (and why did you switch?) Does the render have this ghost color, or just in the view port?

Comment: Hi, i´ m using cycles render now and i noticed that in Material view the new material is showing and also rendering but when i go to solid mode i see a bicolor mesh, still i don´ t understand why.

 i really messed with it because i thought at the beginning that i was on cycles render but when i tried to appl a material i notices it was different, but i didn´t knew why at the beginning, so i started clicking everything and like creating materials, deleting nodes. so that´s also why i changed because i was trying to work on it since the beginning.